# Ruby string substitution

Tags: ruby

Don't know what the term is called (substitution?), but in python if you type

```
num1 = 4  
num2 = 2  
print("Lucky numbers: %d %d" %(num1, num2))
```

You get "Lucky numbers: 4 2"

How do I do this in ruby?

Trying to do the above scenario, it works if I have one variable, but if I need to sub in multiple variables the parentheses aren't valid syntax.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
num1 = 4  
num2 = 2  
print "Lucky numbers: %d %d" % [num1, num2]
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use something called *string interpolation* in Ruby to accomplish this.

ex:

```
num1 = 4  
num2 = 2  
puts "Lucky numbers: #{num1} #{num2}";
```

Here each variable that is inside the #{} is interpreted not as a String but as a variable name and the value is substituted.

Comment: Note that this solves the specific need for integers, and is generally a good Ruby idiom, but does not allow sprintf formatting like `"%.3f"`

Comment: @Phrogz Correct, but the question was about substitution, not formatting.

Comment: Maybe what I was looking for is formatting. I just wanted to be able to create strings like that and then pass them off to other methods

Comment: @Keikoku If you were looking for formatting you should have said that in your question.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of interpolations you can do in a single string? For example `puts "hello #{a} #{b} #{c}"`

Answer (score 7):

```
n1, n2 = 17, 42
puts "Lucky single number: %d" % n1
puts "Lucky multiple numbers: %d %d" % [ n1, n2 ]
puts "Lucky inline interpolation: #{n1} #{n2}"
```

For documentation of the formatting allowed in [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) method read up on [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a hash for string substitution. This is useful if you have multiple instances that need be replaced with the same string.

```
p "%{foo} == %{foo}" % {:foo => "bar" }
# => "bar == bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby methods that most closely mimics that syntax in Python are `sprintf` and `format`, which are aliases for each other. You can read about them in depth in the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Here's an example:

```
num1 = 4
num2 = 2
sprintf("Lucky numbers: %d %d", num1, num2)
```

This would output: "Lucky Numbers: 4 2"

Parenthesis are of course optional.

Answer (score 1):

It's called print formatting.

Checkout more examples [Ruby Formatted Printing](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=r109/d4_6)

Have you tried anything like `"%d"%10`  ? It evaluates to `"10"`

```
1.9.3-p0 :003 > "%02x"%(10)
 => "0a" 
1.9.3-p0 :004 > 

1.9.3-p0 :005 > print "Nicely formatted string with an int: %d" % 10
Nicely formatted string with an int: 10 => nil 
1.9.3-p0 :006 >
```